# Using jQuery, how to make a dropdown menu reappear after an auto redirect and clicking the back button?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Within my code below, when selecting 'Animals' in the dropdown menu a second dropdown menu appears. Selecting any item within this second dropdown menu causes a page redirect. When you click the back button in the browser, this second dropdown menu disappears in every browser besides Firefox. I want the user to be able to change their animal selection, e.g. choose 'Cat' first, then go back and choose 'Bird'.

Is there any way to get the second dropdown menu to reappear without using a jQuery history plugin?

*This code does not behave as I have described in jsfiddle, so have pasted it here:*

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#animal_cat').hide();

$('#search_collquery').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'animals') { 
        $("#animal_cat").show();
    } else {
        $("#animal_cat").hide();
    }
});           

$('#search_catquery').change(function(){      
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + $(this).val();
});        
});                            
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Search Collections:</p>
<select id="search_collquery">
<option selected="selected"> - Select One -</option>
<option value="animals">Animals</option>
<option value="trees">Trees</option>
</select>     
<div id="animal_cat"><p>Search Animal category:</p>
Category: <select id="search_catquery">
<option value="">-- None --</option>
<option>Dogs</option>
<option>Cats</option>
<option>Birds</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: The answer I found to this is to use window.location.hash and window.onload:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#animal_cat').hide();
    $('#search_collquery').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 'animals') {
            $("#animal_cat").show();
        } else {
            $("#animal_cat").hide();
        }
    });

    $('#search_catquery').change(function() {
        window.location.hash = "animal_selected";
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/search?q = " + $(this).val();
    });
});

window.onload = function() {
    if(window.location.hash === '#animal_selected') {
        $('#animal_cat').show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Either store it in a cookie or a hashtag, which you then read on pagereload. Can't see a way of getting around it without taking some kind of tracking into consideration :)

Comment: Thanks for that, Marco. I'm also puzzled as to why it works in Firefox but not in the other browsers. There must be some sort of caching involved...

Comment: Firefox has autofill forms. Which means it remembers a forms information, other browser like IE dosent :)

Answer (score 0):

Created the js with a plugin called cookie, download here https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/tTHKn/

```
$('select').each( function() {
     var cookiename = $(this).attr('id');
     var searchCookie = $.cookie(cookiename);

    if(searchCookie != null) {
     //select from cookie
        $(this).children("option:contains("+searchCookie+")").attr('selected',true);
    }
});


$('select').change( function() {
    var select= $(this);
    var selectId = select.attr('id');
    var selectVal = select.children('option:selected').val();
     //add selected to cookie
    $.cookie(selectId, selectVal, { expires: 7 });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Marco. This is useful for when I need to use a plugin. I was avoiding it because I do feel sometimes that plugins do more than I need them to. With some help, I was able to get the desired outcome using window.location.hash and window.onload. See my update above.

Comment: No problem. It's always a cons vs pros. Im just wondering, the soloution you posted - it dosent seem to to take the "selected" value into account. So the user would still have to select the choices again?

Comment: Yeah, when the user clicks the back button, their choice is still 'selected' and so they'll just be switching to another selection which is exactly what I wanted. For some reason, just calling it via .show() again doesn't reset it - works for me! :)